# Use sphinx to convert Latex,How to set the tableheader color?

Tags: tables, color, sphinx

I use sphinx to generate pdf, But I want to set the tableheader color? How to set?[image]

The tables it produces via latex are pretty ugly, so I'd like to give them some global styling. What I'd like to achieve is a header row color?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! Please post a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) for the tex coe generiated by sphinx. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. The code should compile and be *as small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. Cutting your code down to a MWE may well reveal what your problem actually is. In any case, it is really difficult to help you without more information.

Comment: In my documention, I also want to make chinese font use Microsoft YaHei, the english font and Arabic numerals use Arial font??  and how can I set in conf.py??@Andrew

Comment: Questions about conf.py should be addressed to a suitable stackexhange web site for python. The latex aspects of your question are appropriate for TeX.SX but it is not possible to answer them without more details and, ideally, a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228).

Comment: @Andrew,I'm using sphinx to generate documentations. The tables it produces via latex are pretty ugly, so I'd like to give them some global styling.  I'd like to achieve a  tableheader row color. I add the code in my `conf.py` `preamble`:`\usepackage{tabu,tabulary}` 
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} \definecolor{tablehead}{rgb}{153, 153, 153}` but it does not work

Comment: I understand that. If you want help on TeX.SX then post a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228)!

Comment: @Andrew I'm using sphinx to generate documentations. The tables it produces via latex are pretty ugly, so I'd like to give them some global styling. What I'd like to achieve is a header row color. but I do not know how to do? I have tried but It does not work

Comment: at@jfbu yes I did .I have see the [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236296/override-table-in-sphinx],And I add three directive code`\usepackage{tabu,tabulary}``\usepackage[table]{xcolor}``\definecolor{tablehead}{rgb}{0.7294117647058823, 0.6823529411764706, 0.6235294117647059}` in my `conf.py``preamble`,But I do not the meaning about **% redefine the L column type** `\newcolumntype{L}{X[l]<{\strut}}``\renewenvironment{tabulary}[3]
 {\noindent\tabu to \textwidth{#2}\hline\rowcolor{tablehead}}
 {\endtabu}`,

Comment: Is  is means I modify the .tex file? I feel confused, I know any changes should be adjusted in the `conf.py` `preamble`

Comment: @jfbu sorry, Now I find a new problem, in my documention, I set my font via `fontpkg':'\\usepackage{YaHei Consolas Hybrid}`,But I hope englisn and number in the text use `Arial font` ,such as chapter 1 contents and others in the text, And the chinese in the text use `YaHei Consolas Hybrid font `,How can I set?