# Custom command to configure table style

Tags: environments, tabularx, tabulary, sphinx

I'm using `sphinx` to generate our company manuals. In our legacy manuals we have a certain table style, that we would like to keep.

The table style consists of tables having a header with dark green background, then there are several light-green background rows and after that several rows with a white background.

`Sphinx` generates my LaTeX input files, which are then made an PDF using PdfLatex. There is the possibility to include LaTeX specific comments right before the LaTeX table starts with `:raw-role:`.

The input RST file:

```
.. role:: raw-role(raw)
   :format: latex

:raw-role:`\firstRow`   

=== === ===
 A   B   C
=== === ===
1A   1B  1C
2A   2B  2C
3A   3B  3C
4A   4B  4C
=== === ===
```

Will be transformed into:

```
\firstRow

\noindent\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{|L|L|L|}
\hline
\sphinxstylethead{\relax 
A
\unskip}\relax &\sphinxstylethead{\relax 
B
\unskip}\relax &\sphinxstylethead{\relax 
C
\unskip}\relax \\
\hline
1A
&
1B
&
1C
\\
\hline
2A
&
2B
&
2C
\\
\hline
3A
&
3B
&
3C
\\
\hline
4A
&
4B
&
4C
\\
\hline\end{tabulary}
```

I'm now in need for a command called `\firstRow` that modifies the behaviour of the `\tabulary` environment, so that the header has a dark-green background, the first row beneath has a light-green background and the remaining rows having a white background.

A similar [Question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/236308/127635) was already asked a while ago:

I know that this is not a specific LaTeX question, but I think it is still the right place to ask it here.

Answer (score 1):

As one can not mark across sites duplicates, I only point out here in order not to leave this question unanswered that it is duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42949129/change-latex-table-style-using-sphinx/ and has received as such an answer there.